# What does an Alembic revision ID represent?

Tags: sqlalchemy, django-south, revision, directed-acyclic-graphs, alembic

I have just started looking at Alembic, and coming from Django, where we have [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) to migrate our database schemas (which is [soon](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/) to be included) which uses a friendly old fixed-width number like `0037_fix_my_schema.py` to talk about the order in which migrations are to be applied, I am naturally intrigued by Alembic's revision ID. Is there a DAG backing Alembic, or can someone give a little overview of its internals in this respect?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I took a look myself. The [source](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/src/efecc6c178d7b62f3d5ee35f2bf51ab79d310cdd/alembic/util.py?at=master#cl-253) says:

```py
def rev_id():
    val = int(uuid.uuid4()) % 100000000000000
    return hex(val)[2:-1]
```

Not so fascinating.